# Android wifi and bluetooth scanning for location

Tags: android-location

Is there any intent to open the wifi and bluetooth scanning intent to ask the user to improve location accuracy?

[image: Example]

UPDATE: I found a better way to ask directly the user to activate the Wifi Scanning doing this:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
if (wifiManager.isScanAlwaysAvailable()==false) {
   startActivity(new Intent(WifiManager.ACTION_REQUEST_SCAN_ALWAYS_AVAILABLE));
}
```

**So, my question now is: How can I do same thing to request scan always available for bluetooth? What Intent should I use?**

The way to get to that screen is as follows:

For Nougat: Open Android settings, go to Location, 3 dots menu at top-right, Scanning.

For Oreo: Open Android settings, go to Security & Location, Location, Scanning

For Pie: Open Android settings, go to Location, Advanced, Scanning.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [LocationSettingsRequest](https://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings) to prompt the user to enable location. In the request set `builder.setNeedBle(true);` to enable bluetooth scanning.

User will not be asked to enable bluetooth scanning if bluetooth is already switched on.

Answer (score 0):

> Continuously scanning for Bluetooth can affect your device performance
>   and battery life. So consider this under your own risk.

The code below keeps checking for the devices even after Discovery gets finished. 
First, make sure you register the receiver by using

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED); 
registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);
```

And try running the code.

```
private BluetoothAdapter mBtAdapter;
mBtAdapter.startDiscovery();

private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            // When discovery finds a device
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action))
            {
            //do something
            }

            else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action))
            {
                Log.v(TAG,"Entered the Finished ");
                mBtAdapter.startDiscovery();
            }
```

Comment: I don't think this is the answer to what I asked. Your code is the result of searching for available bluetooth devices to pair. What I ask is in another thing. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Ton have you checked [this one](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE)?

Comment: What I am trying to find is this screen: Open Android settings, go to Location, Advanced, Scanning. See my edited answer